# Read IP addresses from a text file and calculate if it's inside a ip range or cidr block with a command line batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, ip, cidr

I have a text file with a bunch of IP Addresses as follows:

```
200.48.123.45
143.150.41.12
170.12.39.232
```

and so on.

I need to program a batch file that read every single line of the text file and calculate if that IP address is inside this ip range ([IP Range](https://www.countryipblocks.net/e_country_data/PE_range.txt)) or cidr block ([CIDR Block](https://www.countryipblocks.net/e_country_data/PE_cidr.txt))
it must be one of these two, the easiest to program.

If the IP Address is NOT inside the range or cird block, it must be write on an output text file.

I haven't seen one batch file like that, thanks.

Comment: It can be Python or Perl too, forgot to say. I don't have any experience with these languages, so a step-by-step would be appreciated

Comment: This is not really a "write me teh codez" kind of site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a perl script with the NetAddr::IP module and the `contains` function.

Comment: Thanks, i will do a research about it.